# Reading multiple NFC tags

Tags: android, nfc

I want read multiple NFC tags and perform action simultaneously,

Ex:

1. Disable wifi
2. Disable Bluetooth
3. Ringing volume change
4. Alarm change

but what I have red it performs only one action which we entered at first.

Is there any way possible read multiple tags and act simultaneously?

Comment: I think android can discover only one tag at a time. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, you can not.
You can have the same result if you implement a custom payload and when your app reads the content starts multiple actions.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion,I dont have any idea how could I do that, tags are written in byte, do I have to read form this byte to this byte for one function and other memory location for another function...Could share any information or any link or any sample for payload reading.

Comment: This link (from my blog) shows how to write a NFC tag http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2016/01/nfc-tag-writer-android.html If you want to read an NFC use this link http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2015/03/nfc-android-read-ndef-tag-2.html. Hope it helps you

Comment: Great,Let me check.